# Similar text without loss of text formatting

Tags: php, regex, string, similarity, preg-replace-callback

### Brief

How I can similar text using function **similar_text()** without loss of text formatting? I want create one function for similar text without loss text formatting in **case insensitive** regex. I have not been able to do anything myself yet. Because I do not understand such operations similar to the case of text and similar text. I tried only with breaking up words by a space using the function of an **explode()**. And my option does not work in any register. Plus, do not return the original format and the original word register in the text. What should I do? What do you prefer to do on this task? How to get around this situation? Of course, the function should also work very quickly, with as much data as possible (**large array**). As correct words, there will initially be one array with the correct variants of words (in the **lower case**). And using these words from the array, you need to correct the text as correctly as possible and in the source register of the word in the text.

## Example:

```
$dict = array(
    "two",
    "occasions",
    "have",
    "been",
    "asked",
    "members",
    "parliament",
    "pray",
    "babbage",
    "you",
    "into",
    "machine",
    "wrong",
    "figures",
    "will",
    "right",
    "answers",
    "come",
    "able",
    "rightly",
    "apprehend",
    "confusion",
    "ideas",
    "question"
);
```

#### Input text:

```
On tw ocasons I hve bee aked [by mebers of Pariamnt]: 'Pry, Mr. Babage, if you put ito the mahine wrng figres, wll the rigt aswers cme out?' I am not ale rghty to aprehend the kind of conusion of idas that could provoke such a quetion. Charles Babbage
```

#### Needed result:

```
On two occasions I have been asked [by members of Parliament]: 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question. Charles Babbage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function similar_correcting($text, $dict)
{
    $step1 = strtolower($text); // text to lower case
    $step2 = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]/iu', ' ', $step1); // delete all without letters a-z
    $input = array_unique(explode(' ', $step2)); // generate new unique array from input text

    $res = array(); // create new associative array for incorrect/correct values for using to replace
    foreach ($input as $in) 
    {
        $match = 0; // set default value to variable match
        foreach ($dict as $correct) // us out dict for checking word in input text array values
        {
            similar_text($correct, $in, $percent); // check for correcting
            if ($percent > $match) // if persent > 0
            {
                $result = $correct; // set to result correct form word
                $match = $percent; 
            }
        }
        $res[$in] = $result; // set to output array res keys founded incorrect values from input text array and set to value correct form words for replace
    }
    // Here we replace all words in input text from associative array $res by replace key to value in input text in any cases
    $response = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($res) {
    $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
    if (isset($res[$word])) {
        $repl = $res[$word];
        if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
        if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
        if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
        for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
        }
        return implode("", $mixed);
    }
    return $m[0];
    }, $text);

    return $response; // and return the closest correct text form.
}

$text = "On tw ocasons I hve bee aked [by mebers of Pariamnt]: 'Pry, Mr. Babage, if you put ito the mahine wrng figres, wll the rigt aswers cme out?' I am not ale rghty to aprehend the kind of conusion of idas that could provoke such a quetion. Charles Babbage";

echo similar_correcting($text, $dict);
```

#### Input text:

On tw ocasons I hve bee aked [by mebers of Pariamnt]: 'Pry, Mr. Babage, if you put ito the mahine wrng figres, wll the rigt aswers cme out?' I am not ale rghty to aprehend the kind of conusion of idas that could provoke such a quetion. Charles Babbage

#### Output text:

Wrong two occasions INTO have been asked [you members two Parliament]: 'Pray, Members. Babbage, into you question into have machine wrong figures, will have right answers come you?' INTO have into able rightly two apprehend have into two confusion two ideas have you apprehend machine have question. Have Babbage

How to get the result wrong. But this is because some words do not exist in the dictionary.

#### Let's add the necessary words to the dictionary

```
$dict = array
(
    "on",
    "two",
    "occasions",
    "i",
    "have",
    "been",
    "asked",
    "by",
    "members",
    "of",
    "parliament",
    "pray",
    "mr",
    "babbage",
    "if",
    "you",
    "put",
    "into",
    "the",
    "machine",
    "wrong",
    "figures",
    "will",
    "right",
    "answers",
    "come",
    "out",
    "am",
    "not",
    "able",
    "rightly",
    "to",
    "apprehend",
    "kind",
    "confusion",
    "ideas",
    "that",
    "could",
    "provoke",
    "such",
    "a",
    "question",
    "charles",
);

$text = "On tw ocasons I hve bee aked [by mebers of Pariamnt]: 'Pry, Mr. Babage, if you put ito the mahine wrng figres, wll the rigt aswers cme out?' I am not ale rghty to aprehend the kind of conusion of idas that could provoke such a quetion. Charles Babbage";

echo similar_correcting($text, $dict);
```

#### Input text:

On tw ocasons I hve bee aked [by mebers of Pariamnt]: 'Pry, Mr. Babage, if you put ito the mahine wrng figres, wll the rigt aswers cme out?' I am not ale rghty to aprehend the kind of conusion of idas that could provoke such a quetion. Charles Babbage

#### Output text:

On two occasions I have been asked [by members of Parliament]: 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question. Charles Babbage

#### Needed text for user:

On two occasions I have been asked [by members of Parliament]: 'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question. Charles Babbage

Comment: There is a lot of code and no explanation. Please explain what you are doing.

Comment: You can see comments code and output results in updated answer @Maciej Jureczko